# After updating some plugin, my wordpress site is currepted. How resolve this?

Tags: wordpress

I don't know after updating which plugin. Now my site is showing all special characters as like below, What to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to  identify plugin conflicts do this.

Go to your plugin folder and rename plugins one by one and and check whether your web site is coming back to the previous state again.
This is the simple way WordPress developers use to identify plugin conflicts. 
cheers :)

Comment: It was a plugin conflict, we fixed it by renaming(to w3-total-cache1) the same, thanks